# How to reduce the delay in triggering Lambda from DynamoDB stream?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am encountering a delay issue with a Lambda function triggered by a DynamoDB stream. Despite configuring the Lambda with Node.js 16.x, a timeout of 5 minutes, and 1536 memory allocation, the trigger takes over 5 minutes to initiate the Lambda execution.

How can I decrease this trigger time? I've attempted to increase Lambda memory and timeout settings, but it hasn't resolved the delay. Any suggestions or insights into optimizing the trigger time would be greatly appreciated.

Lambda settings:

```
NodeJs 16.x
5 minute timeout
1536 memory configuration
```

Answer (score 3):

Your [EventSourceMapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-eventsourcemapping.html) needs configured correctly, it's got nothing to do with your Lambda memory.

5 minutes is the default batch window time. What's happening is you're not meeting the default 100 items in the shard for it to invoke the function,so it's waiting for the batch window to trigger the function.

`Batch size` – The number of records to send to the function in each batch, up to 10,000. Lambda passes all of the records in the batch to the function in a single call, as long as the total size of the events doesn't exceed the payload limit for synchronous invocation (6 MB).

`Batch window` – Specify the maximum amount of time to gather records before invoking the function, in seconds.

My advice is to lower the value for both of these. Batch size should be low enough that you accumulate N amount of changes in Y time. Y being the time you deem reasonable to invoke the function.

Comment: My table needs to have at least 100 items in it for it to trigger instantly? I changed batch size to 1 and window to 5, but lambda still takes few minutes to invoke

Comment: How are you calculating the time? Please share a screenshot of your iterator age metric

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by iterator age metric. How am I suppose to calculate time? Could you clarify please?

Comment: You said theres a delay, how do you know? CloudWatch Lambda Metric, iterator age tells you how long it takes for an item to traverse the stream.

Comment: Here is a link to the screenshot of the iterator age metric. How do I use this information to reduce the invocation time. [iterator age metric image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyQUi.png)

Comment: What's your lambda duration metrics?

Comment: Here are all the metrics. [lambda duration mettrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycSgw.png)

Comment: You've only got a concurrency of 2. Increase your parallelization factor of your lambda

Comment: I changed it to 10. I went into the lambda console -> configuration -> triggers -> selected the table -> edit -> additional settings -> changed CONCURRENT BATCHES PER SHARD to 10
[lambda settings img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXyHb.png)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257293/discussion-between-ishan-patel-and-leeroy-hannigan).